# Dynamically creating multiple RadDocks on a button click

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, telerik

I'm having some problems trying to dynamically create multiple RadDocks at the same time.

What I'd like to achieve is to have multiple Docks added to the DockZone on a button click, but the only thing I get is first Dock properly created and displayed when the rest of them aren't displayed (they are displayed after I refresh the webpage) and they are created but floating outside of the zone.

I have similar scenario when creating one Dock at a time and it works like a charm.

Here is the code:

```
protected void rbAddTickets_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var ticketList = (from t in db.Ticket
                              where t.idManager == idManager && t.Zatvoren == false || t.idManager == null && t.Zatvoren == false
                              select t).ToList();

            var memoTicketList = from t in ticketList
                                 where t.Memo == null || t.Memo == true
                                 orderby t.Firma.Naziv, t.idNadredeniTicket, t.RedniBroj, t.Opis
                                 select t;

            foreach (var ticket in memoTicketList)
            {
                RadDock dock = new RadDock();
                dock.UniqueName = ticket.idTicket.ToString();
                dock.ID = string.Format("RadDock{0}", dock.UniqueName);
                dock.Title = ticket.idNadredeniTicket + "-" + ticket.RedniBroj + " (" + ticket.Firma.Naziv + ")";
                dock.Text = ticket.Opis;
                dock.DockMode = DockMode.Docked;
                //dock.Index = Convert.ToInt32(Session["MinIndex"]) - 1;


                dock.Commands.Add(new DockCloseCommand());
                dock.Commands.Add(new DockExpandCollapseCommand());
                dock.Command += new DockCommandEventHandler(DockCommands);

                //ticket.Memo = true;
                //db.SaveChanges(); OMOGUĆI KASNIJE

                UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(dock);

                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
                dock,
                this.GetType(),
                "AddDock",
                string.Format(@"function _addDock() {{
    Sys.Application.remove_load(_addDock);
    $find('{1}').dock($find('{0}'));
    $find('{0}').doPostBack('DockPositionChanged');
}};
Sys.Application.add_load(_addDock);", dock.ClientID, rdzIncidenti.ClientID),
                true);
                CreateSaveStateTrigger(dock);

            }
        }
```

So, to sum everything up. I would like to generate Docks properly; display them immediately, without having to refresh the page and create them inside DockZone.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encountered behavior appears to be caused by problems in saving/loading the layout of the RadDock controls on the page (the missing docks) and setting different **ID** or/and **UniqueName**, when recreating the RadDocks after a postback (the floating docks).

The online demo [Dock / My Portal](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/dock/examples/myportal/defaultcs.aspx) is a good example of dynamically creating and persisting the state of RadDocks and the scenario it implements is similar to yours, so I would suggest using it as a reference for your further development. The help article [Dynamically Creating RadDock Controls](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/dock-control-creation.html) will also be useful, as it lists the main steps for dynamically creating RadDocks.

Overall, the code that you have provided appears to be correct, although I would suggest adding the new RadDocks in the Controls collection of RadDockLayout and docking them in a particular RadDockZone via the Dock method, when inserted in the page on button click. This is implemented in the **ButtonAddDock_Click** event handler in the linked demo via the following lines of code:

```
    RadDockZone dz = (RadDockZone)FindControl(DropDownZone.SelectedItem.Text);
    //adding the dock to the docklayout and then docking it to the zone to avoid ViewState issues on subsequent postback
    RadDockLayout1.Controls.Add(dock);
    dock.Dock(dz);
```

Since I am mostly guessing as to what the rest of your implementation is, I would recommend examining the provided resources and utilizing them in order to achieve the desired functionality.